# Is there a smarter way to keep the indentation when replacing characters with a regex?

Tags: regex, replace, indentation, keyboard-maestro

I want to replace the *asterisks* in a Markdown list with *hyphens*.

**Example:**

> - 1.0
>
>   - 1.1
>   - 1.2
> - 2
>
>   - 2.1
>
>     - 2.2

Currently I have a separate regex pattern for up to three levels of indentation set up in [Keyboard Maestro](http://keyboardmaestro.com) for Mac:

[image: Keyboard Maestro Search and Replace with a Regex Pattern]

I wonder if there isn't a smarter way to do this and which adresses all kinds of indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use submatching groups and reference them in the replacing string like this:

Regular expression matching your lines with list items: `([\t ]*)\*(.*)`

The string used for replacement: `\1-\2`

Comment: That's great. I still have to think about this for a while until I've made sense of it (^_^).

Answer (score 1):

In many regular expression search and replace systems, you can refer to a parenthesized group in the regular expression in the replacement, using `\1`, `\2`, etc. to refer to each successive group. So for example, in sed you could do:

```
sed -e 's/\(^[\t ]*\)\*/\1-/'
```

I'm not sure if Keyboard Maestro gives you that option. It mentions that it uses ICU regular expressions; if it also uses their replacement options, then you can use `$1`, `$2` etc. to refer to the replacement.

If not, all is not lost. You can use a lookbehind assertion to match the sequence of whitespace before the the asterisk, without including the asterisk as part of the match; then just use a single dash as your replacement:

```
Search for: (?<=^[\t ]*)\*
Replace with: -
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. Now I know how to do a search and replace with `sed` and will incorporate it in other scripts. By the way, Keyboard Maestro allows using replacements. So after @przemyslaw-kruglej's solution I just needed to enter `$1-$2`.